# ListView или RecyclerView Filter

Tags: java, android, listview, recyclerview, retrofit

Получаю через ретрофит списки, хочу сделать фильтр через EditText или SearchView находил в гугле кучу вариантов но не один не могу подставить под свой код, помогите пожалуйста =)

Вариант с ListView :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView countryNameText;
    TextView regionText;
    TextView subRegionText;
    EditText search;

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        countryNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country_name_id);
        regionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.region_id);
        subRegionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_reg_id);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_id);

        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput("countries_file");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            final ArrayList<Countrys> returnlist = (ArrayList<Countrys>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, returnlist));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    Countrys countrys = returnlist.get(position);
                    mIntent.putExtra("key", countrys);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                }
            });
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





        Retrofit.getCountries(new Callback<List<Countrys>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final List<Countrys> countries, Response response) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "получили данные");


                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = openFileOutput("countries_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    oos.writeObject(countries);
                    oos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, countries));
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                        Countrys countrys = countries.get(position);
                        mIntent.putExtra("key", countrys);
                        startActivity(mIntent);
                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Countrys> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Countrys> objects) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textNameofCoutry = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.country_name_id);
                holder.textRegion = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.region_id);
                holder.textSubRegion = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.post_reg_id);
                rowView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }

            Countrys countries = getItem(position);
            holder.textNameofCoutry.setText(countries.getName());
            holder.textRegion.setText(countries.getRegion());
            holder.textSubRegion.setText(countries.getSubregion());


            return rowView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {

            public TextView textNameofCoutry;
            public TextView textRegion;
            public TextView textSubRegion;
        }


    }
}
```

Вариант с RecyclerView

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView countryNameText;
    TextView regionText;
    TextView subRegionText;
    EditText search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        countryNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country_nameId);
        regionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.region_id);
        subRegionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sub_region_id);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_id);


        final RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Retofit.getCountries(new Callback<List<Countries>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final List<Countries> countries, Response response) {

                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                list.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(countries, new OnItemClickWatcher<Countries>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View v, int position, Countries item) {
                        Intent mintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                        Countries countries1 = countries.get(position);
                        mintent.putExtra("Key", countries1);
                        startActivity(mintent);
                    }
                }));

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }

    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

        private OnItemClickWatcher<Countries> watcher;
        List<Countries> countries;


        public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Countries> countries, OnItemClickWatcher<Countries> watcher){
            this.countries = countries;
            this.watcher = watcher;


        }



        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,false);
            return new ViewHolder(v, watcher, countries);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i) {
            holder.name.setText(countries.get(i).getName());
            holder.region.setText(countries.get(i).getRegion());
            holder.subregion.setText(countries.get(i).getSubregion());
          holder.image.setImageResource(countries.get(i).getImage());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return countries.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }




        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            private TextView name;
            private TextView region;
            private TextView subregion;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickWatcher<Countries> watcher, final List<Countries> names) {
                super(itemView);
                name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_nameId);
                region = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.region_id);
                subregion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_region_id);
              subregion = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        watcher.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), names.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Вам нужны два списка объектов в адаптере. Один основной, не отображаемый. Второй же наполнять отображаемыми, отфильтрованными данными и его отображать.
2. Также нужен метод в адаптере, принимающий строку (или ещё что), очищающий отображаемый список данных и пробегающийся циклом по основному списку с данными, находя средь них подходящие и добавляя их в список отображаемых данных. После черего адаптер надо уведомить об изменении данных вызовом `notifyDataSetChanged()`
3. Теперь при вводе данных в текстовое поле вам надо получить ваш адаптер и вызвать на нём метод из второго пункта, передав в него введённый текст.

Comment: Ну смысл я и так понимал, реализовать только не могу)

Comment: @Azarnoy, а что именно не реализовать? Создать переменную типа `ArrayList` на уровне класса вы же можете?..

Comment: Ну создать конечно, но весь код в целом не представляю.

Comment: @Azarnoy, ну а метод в адаптере создать со строкой-аргументом и в нём циклом по списку данных пробежаться сможете?

Comment: примерно, не уверен, это взять мой лист и через for each пройти?

Comment: Да. И внутри цикла сравнить элементы списка с условием и доавить их в отображаемый список. После уведомить адаптер об изменениях. А перед циклом очистить отображаемый список

Comment: Так всегда) Начните делать, гуглить и все получится)